# Copy or move a document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I see lots of threads on copying files from one document library to another, but i want to move or copy a complete document library from one site to another (within the same site collection).

Is this possible with .NET C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible - this is where specialized Backup solutions from third party vendors come in.

If you are talking about a simple document library it is of course not that hard:

- You first create a new document library at your destination and apply all your settings you have on your current library
- Secondly you just have to iterate over all documents in the library and use use the `SPFolder.Add` command

  `SPFileCollection collFile = collFolder.Files;
  foreach(SPFile file in collFile)
  destFolder.Files.Add(file.Name, file.OpenBinary());`

The collFolder in this case is the original document libary. The destFolder is the new document library. You can get the doc libs as a folder by using `SPWeb.GetFolder(string doclibname)`.

Comment: I believe SPFile only has CopyTo which only can be used in the same site. In order to copy the file to a new doc lib you need to do a SPFolder.Files.Add where you input the file.OpenBinary()..

Comment: You might be very correct - I only wrote what came to my mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

We use ControlPoint in our company to do these kind of item and list/doclib copies. I don't even have to dirty my hands with Powershell or STSADM anymore (apart from the stuff I like to get my hands dirty with). Awesome tool and a great Tech Support team there too.

Comment: I created such webpart with above requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by saving list as template with "include content" flag selected and recreating new list from template in destination site.

1. Go to list settings and choose "Save list as template"
2. Fill in the fields and check the "Include Content" checkbox.
3. Go to your destination site.
4. Go to Site Actions -> More Options. Select your template you have saved before.
5. You are done.

Please note that you cannot copy list this way if you have made any customization for the list related only to source site (e.g. started workflow on item).

To do this programamtically, just use [SPListist.SaveAsTemplate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.saveastemplate.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try just to open source and target `SPWeb` objects and copy items between them one by one. You may want to read this article:
http://blog.mediawhole.com/2007/12/copying-sharepoint-document-library.html.

The author shows how to copy document library from one site to another that resides in the same web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Central Admin you can perform a granular backup of certain document library. Than you can restore it under any desired web site. This solution should be faster than copying (and deleting) items one by one. For backup and restore see more on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open both libraries in explorer view and copy the items. But this is no code solution and does not copy metadata.